# Sysprep Azure VM with Remote PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, virtual-machine, sysprep

I am trying to SysPrep a VM in Azure via Azure DevOps YAML pipelines. In the same pipeline (previous stage), I am deploying the VM via Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates and copying scripts and files to the machine. I want to automate the whole process so RDP'ing into the machine is not an option. When I run SysPrep on the VM, I am getting the following error message:

```
##[error]The remote session query failed for <insertMyFQDN>.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com with the following error message: Access is denied.
```

From my repo I have a couple of files, including a PowerShell script that SysPreps the machine (sysPrepvm.ps1) - taken from [Run SysPrep remotely through commands from Azure powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144405/run-sysprep-remotely-through-commands-from-azure-powershell). The script works when I am logged in on the machine and run in manually.

**sysPrepvm.ps1**

```
$sysPrepPath = 'C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe'
$arguments = '/generalize /oobe /shutdown /quiet'
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($sysPrepPath,$arguments) Start-Process -FilePath $sysPrepPath -ArgumentList $arguments} -ArgumentList $sysPrepPath,$arguments
```

I am using the built-in task in Azure DevOps, "Powershell on Target Machines", with which I am able to invoke other commands or scripts, so I am confident that the task works.

**My Stage in the YAML Pipeline looks like this:**

```
- stage: 
  displayName: SysPrep
  variables: 
   azFQDN: $[stageDependencies.Connect.connect.outputs['SetEnvVars.azFQDN']]
  jobs:
  - job: SysPrepVhD
    steps:
    - task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
      inputs:
        Machines: '$(azFQDN)' # FQDN on the machine
        UserName: '$(adminUser)'
        UserPassword: '$(adminPw)'
        ScriptType: 'FilePath'
        ScriptPath: 'C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\fishtank\sysPrepvm.ps1'
```

Is there a limitation of running this remotely? I haven't been able to find a work-around yet, so any answer is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I have also tried running the script with -Verb RunAs, as an Inline script instead of File, as well as tried the accepted answer on the previous post:

[Sysprep an Azure VM using PowerShell task in a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908086/sysprep-an-azure-vm-using-powershell-task-in-a-pipeline)

Comment: Have you tried `Start-Process` with `-Verb RunAs`?

Comment: I just tried, though with no luck unfortunately. Same error message.

Comment: Did you look at this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144405/run-sysprep-remotely-through-commands-from-azure-powershell

Comment: Yes. The script I'm using (sysPrepvm.ps1) is the accepted answer from that post.

Comment: The error says "Access is denied". You need to check your credentials of your VM.

Comment: The error only says access denied when calling the sysprep file. I have tested with other script files in the same directory, which work. What I do suspect, though, is that when the script that executes sysprep begins the user which remote powershell uses gets deleted in the process, which it should but sysprep should continue, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way using Custom Script Extension instead. I didn't think of doing this at first, since the ARM template I am using already has a Custom Script Extension on the machine to enable WinRM, and cannot have multiple Custom Script Extensions installed at the same time. Also, I didn't want to execute SysPrep as soon as the machine booted because it had to run other scripts and settings first. In my YAML pipeline, I managed to remove the existing one to redeploy a new Custom Script Extension with the script included.

I posted the entire solution on GitHub - https://github.com/Crytlig/azsysprep - for anyone in interested. It obviously needs a bit of cleaning but it works as is.